# Unable to update to specific cordova version using npm

Tags: cordova, npm, command-line-interface

So I'm getting this error when trying to upgrade my cordova version to cordova@3.5.0-0.2.4 to match another programmer's machine.

```
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream/0.0.5
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/hoek/-/hoek-0.9.1.tgz
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/man/man7'
npm ERR! error rolling back  cordova-lib@0.21.3 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/man/man7']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 53,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/man/man7' }
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/man/man7/npm-scripts.7'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "cordova@3.5.0-0.2.4"
npm ERR! cwd /tfs/MobileApplications/Main/CrossPlatform/EESEmployee
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.24
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.21
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/man/man7/npm-scripts.7
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/man/man7/npm-scripts.7
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
npm ERR! <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
npm ERR!  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
npm ERR! <html>
npm ERR!   <head>
npm ERR!     <title>200 OK</title>
npm ERR!   </head>
npm ERR!   <body>
npm ERR!     <h1>Error 200 OK</h1>
npm ERR!     <p>OK</p>
npm ERR!     <h3>Guru Meditation:</h3>
npm ERR!     <p>XID: 724797158</p>
npm ERR!     <hr>  
npm ERR!     <p>Varnish cache server</p>
npm ERR!   </body>
npm ERR! </html>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     at Object.parse (native)
npm ERR!     at RegClient.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:241:23)
npm ERR!     at Request.self.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:123:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:893:14)
npm ERR!     at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:844:12)
npm ERR!     at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at _stream_readable.js:920:16
npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "cordova@3.5.0-0.2.4" 
npm ERR! cwd /tfs/MobileApplications/Main/CrossPlatform/EESEmployee
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.24
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.21
npm ERR! type unexpected_token
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tfs/MobileApplications/Main/CrossPlatform/EESEmployee/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Here's the last bit of the nom-debug.log file, don't plan on trying to submit 10k+ lines of debug logs.

```
12886 error Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/man/man7/npm-scripts.7'
12887 error If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
12887 error including the npm and node versions, at:
12887 error     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
12888 error System Darwin 12.5.0
12889 error command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "cordova@3.5.0-0.2.4"
12890 error cwd /tfs/MobileApplications/Main/CrossPlatform/EESEmployee
12891 error node -v v0.10.24
12892 error npm -v 1.3.21
12893 error path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/man/man7/npm-scripts.7
12894 error fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/man/man7/npm-scripts.7
12895 error fstream_type File
12896 error fstream_class FileWriter
12897 error code ENOENT
12898 error errno 34
12899 error fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
12899 error fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
12900 verbose exit [ 34, true ]
```

I have used 'sudo npm cache clean' and I have cleared the '~/.npm' file.  Trying to update the cordova version has removed my old cordova version (3.3.0-…) so I'll either have to get this fixed or try to get the newest version soon… but we're trying to keep the cordova versions on our developers computers the same for different projects.

Comment: Removing @3.5.0-0.2.4 from the command allowed me to retrieve the latest version which is just off by the minor version number (3.5.0-0.2.6).  I would still like to know if there was some reason why I couldn't download 0.2.4 in case this comes up in the future.